# Struct within another struct Solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I just started learning solidity and I am working on a bidding contract that allows bidders to bid on a campaign.
I have a struct for campaigns. Bidders have details (address, name), I want to store bidders with their information inside of the campaign.  There can be more than one bidder for a campaign

This is my Campaign and Bidder struct

```
struct Campaign {
    uint256 campaignID;
    uint256 budget;
    uint256 bidCount;

}
 struct Bidder {
    bool bided;
    uint256 bid;
    string name;
    address bidderAddress;

}
mapping(address => Bidder) public bidders;
Campaign[] public campaigns;
```

I wrote down a bid function here that takes the index of campaign and bid then populate bidCount.

```
function bid(uint256 _bidIndex, uint256 _twitterID) public {
    require(!bidders[msg.sender].bided);

    bidders[msg.sender].bid = _bidIndex;
    campaigns[_bidIndex].bidCount += 1;
    totalBids += 1;
}
```

So the Campaign can look something like this (if this is possible)

```
0: campaignID 1
1: budget 2ETH
2: bidCount 3
3: Bidder {0: name Bidder1, 1: address 0xahaaahha}
          {0: name Bidder2, 2: address 0x2334jddd}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, in this case you can use nested mapping into Campaign struct for 'connect' different bids to a single campaign. I created a smart contract ad hoc for your case, you can see it in the following lines:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Auction {
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Campaign {
        uint256 campaignID;
        uint256 budget;
        uint256 bidCount;
        mapping(uint => Bidder[]) bidders;
    }

    struct Bidder {
        bool bided;
        uint256 bid;
        string name;
        address bidderAddress;
    }

    Campaign[] public campaigns;
    uint totalCampaign = 0;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Error! You're not the smart contract owner!");
        _;
    }

    // Create campaigns
    function createCampaing(uint _budgetCampaign) public onlyOwner {
        Campaign storage _firstCampaigns = campaigns.push();
        _firstCampaigns.campaignID = totalCampaign;
        _firstCampaigns.budget = _budgetCampaign;
        totalCampaign++;
    }

    // Bid 
    function bid(uint _indexCampaign, string memory _nameBidder) public {
        Campaign storage _bidCampaign = campaigns[_indexCampaign];
        _bidCampaign.bidCount += 1;
        uint _bidIndex = _bidCampaign.bidCount;
        _bidCampaign.bidders[_indexCampaign].push(Bidder(true, _bidIndex, _nameBidder, msg.sender));
    }

    // Getter Bids
    function getBids(uint _indexCampaign) onlyOwner external view returns(Bidder[] memory) {
        return campaigns[_indexCampaign].bidders[_indexCampaign];
    }
}
```

With `getBids()` function, you retrieve all bids for a specific campaign that it identify with its index. I put a onlyOwner modifier that it allows to specific function that they'll call only from the smart contract owner (rather who deployed for first time smart contract into blockchain).

Comment: This works for me. Thank you so much
--

@Kerry99 One last thing - the `getBids()` function returns a tuple, is there any way it can return like a list? similar to how its returned for `campaign(1)`. Why because I am not sure if I can read the tuple data from the frontend because of the way its displayed.